# How could i split a circle in flutter/dart and make it visually equal?

Tags: flutter, dart, split, geometry, containers

I tryied to create a Pizza that is able to be split in pieces...
The circle itself aint been any Problem, as its a rounded Container, but to cut it by lets say "1-8 pieces", and make it possible to split it individually, and get the circle equally fair splitted visually.  If someone could help me with this, i would really appreciate it as im pretty new to Flutter/Dart, and couldnt find any workaround for this problem.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart). It adds pie charts to flutter. This will probably cover your use case.